# html php title not work

Tags: php, html

I want to set title of this welcome page, but my code does not work. Where is the problem? Thanks all.

index.php:

```
$page = "";
include('layout/meta.php');

if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'welcome') {
        $page = 'welcome';
        include('layout/welcome.php');
}
```

layout/meta.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php
        if($page == 'welcome') { ?>
            <title>Welcome</title>
            <?php
        }
        if($page == 'home') { ?>
            <title>Home</title>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
```

Comment: Move the include below the `if(isset($_GET` clause.

Comment: Define `$page = 'welcome';` before you call `include('layout/meta.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, `$page` is assigning after this, so you need to either assign first or user `$_GET['page']`.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'welcome') { ?>
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <?php
    }
    if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'home') { ?>
        <title>Home</title>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try with this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you pass pagename in the GET parameter where you can get it using **PHP global variables**, this is how you get the page filename.

```
$filename=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); // Returns the current PHP File name
```

Now use it as below.

```
<?php if($filename == 'welcome.php') { ?>
        <title>Welcome</title>
<?php } else if($filename == 'home.php') { ?>
        <title>Home</title>
<?php } ?>
```

This will simplify your code with less efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a switch control structure ? it can spare you resources, also, you code isn't very readable to me, I prefer to use [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) in situations like yours, i.e.:

```
<?php
switch($page){
    case "home":
        $page = "<title>Home</title>";
        break;

    case "welcome":
        $page = "<title>Home</title>";
        break;
}

echo <<< EOF
<html>
    <head>
        {$title}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
EOF;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
Index.php 
include('layout/meta.php');

if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'welcome') {
        $data['page'] = 'welcome';
        include('layout/welcome.php',$data);
}
```

I hope it help you